# On C/C++ dereferencing operator

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have a little doubt on this subject:

If I have:

```
int a = 11;
int *b = &a;
```

when I do:

```
&*b
```

I get the address of `a` pointed by `b` so my question is:

does the dereferencing operator return the variable pointed or the value of that variable?

Comment: You can think of it as returning a reference to the object. In the same way that a function returning an lvalue reference is an lvalue, so is the unary `*` operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> does the dereferencing operator return the variable pointed or the value of that variable?

It returns an *lvalue* referring to the object that is pointed (i.e. the *variable pointed* in your own terms). If you use it in a context where an *rvalue* is needed the *lvalue-to-rvalue* conversion will be applied (i.e. the *value of that variable* will be read out of the variable).

Comment: So is it more correct to say that unary * returns the variable pointed and no directly the value?

Comment: @xdevel2000: I prefer not to use *variable* in this context. The term *variable* usually has other implications (like it having a name), but yes it yields the *object*, not the *value*. (Re. *variable*, consider: `int *p = new int(5);`, the expression `*p` yields an object, but that is not a *variable* in the program --`p` is a variable, but `*p` is not) [All this assumes that we are dealing with pointers, and not objects overloading `operator*`]

Answer (score 5):

```
b == &a
```

so

```
*b == a
```

so

```
&*b == &(*b) == &(a)
```

Comment: You nailed it in a simple and smart fashion :)

Comment: You have a typo or an error in the first line, `b == &a`, `*b == a`.